# SVG element not on top after drag

Tags: drag-and-drop, svg, highcharts

I am using HighStock for charts in my screen. I have different flags on my series on random points.

I have a requirement to drag and drop the flags to anywhere in the chart.

here is the fiddle of that http://jsfiddle.net/X7AHK/13.

I am able to drag the flag but when i drop the flag, i cannot see it. The flag element is still there on the place where it was dropped, if u mouseover to that place you can see the icon changing.

I guess there is problem of overlaying the element?

Comment: Could you clarify: what are the 'flags' on the chart that can be dragged and dropped? I understand your problem and (as shown below) can tell you generally how to solve it, but I cannot reproduce it specifically and thus cannot advise how to implement a solution. (I cannot drag and move the "On Series" item, if that is your 'flag'.)

Answer (score 1):

SVG uses a ["painters model"](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/render.html#PaintersModel) for its rendering, which means that elements that come earlier in the source code/DOM can always be drawn over by items that appear later in the source/DOM. (This is in contrast to HTML which has the `z-index` property to allow re-ordering items.)

As such, if you want to move an item to the 'top', you need to re-insert the item at another point in the DOM. For example, see [this demo](http://phrogz.net/SVG/drag_under_transformation.xhtml); drag the blue and red boxes so that they overlap and then alternatingly click on each. This is accomplished by line 94 in the source code:

```js
el.parentNode.appendChild(el); // move to top
```

The comment is slightly misleading, insofar as the element isn't moved to the absolute *top*, but rather to be drawn last of all its siblings. If you look at the source DOM, you'll see (simplified):

```xml
<svg ...>
  <g transform="scale(1.2,0.8)">
    <rect class="drag resize" ... fill="#c66"/>
    <rect class="drag resize" ... fill="#69c"/>
  </g>
  <circle class="drag sizer" ... r="5"/>
  <circle class="drag sizer" ... r="5"/>
</svg>
```

Thus, when you click on a rectangle it is reordered to be the last child in the `<g>`roup, rendering after the other rectangle in the group, but always rendering before the yellow circles that are drawn atop the corners.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i have a requirement to have images on random points of the series. and then user could drag and drop the images on different points in charts. for that i was trying to use flags drag and drop solution. Can you suggest how can i achieve that functionality?? 


I think Highstock renders multiple rect elements on top of each other to make a flag, and when i click on a flag, the event is fired on the top most element and only that is dragged. 

have a look at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/X7AHK/16/) . Can you pleases suggest a solution in that..?? Thanks